# Find posterior coin tossing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $Y$ is the number of heads in $n$ tosses of a coin, binomially distributed with index n and parameter $\theta$ and that the prior distribution of $\theta$ is of Beta form with density $\pi(\theta) \propto \theta^{(a-1)}(1-\theta)^{(b-1)}$. I have to find the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $Y=y$.

I thought:

$\pi(\theta|y)=\dfrac{\pi(\theta)f(x;\theta)}{\int \pi(\theta)f(x;\theta) d\theta}= \dfrac{\theta^{a+y-1}(1-\theta)^{n-y+b-1}\dbinom{n}{y}}{\int_{0}^{1}\theta^{a+y-1}(1-\theta)^{n-y+b-1}\dbinom{n}{y}}=\dfrac{\theta^{(a+x-1)}(1-\theta)^{(n-x+b-1)}}{B(a+x,b+n-x)}$

My first question is if this is correct. 
Second I have to know,  in the case that the tossing yields 1 tail and $n-1$ heads, how large $n$ should be in orde that we would just give odds of 2 to 1 in favour of a head occurating at the next toss. I have no idea how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are correct. Now note that you ended up with a new beta distribution whose parameters are $a'=a+x$ and $b'=b+n-x$ and an expectation of $\frac{a+x}{a+b+n}$ which you want, with $x=1$, to be $\frac{1}{3}$ (or at least that's how I understand the second question).